# PrintPreview in JavaFX

Tags: html, javafx, printing

I'm working on javafx application that displays (locally stored) html documents. 
The problem that I have is making a possibility to display print preview dialog. This dialog needs to have ability to show how will pages of some particular html document be printed (with possibility to change margins).

As far as I searched there is no embedded mechanism in javafx to accomplish this. I hope I'm wrong. Is there any free lib that I can use? Or any other suggestion?